# Two Var Function

Tags: calculus, functions

I hate min and max questions.

I have a function
$$G(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{y}+\frac{9}{4-x-y}.$$

I need to prove that $G(x,y)$ has a minimum value of $9$.

I've partially derived them for $x$ and $y$ giving
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{9}{(4-x-y)^2}=0\tag 1$$
$$\frac{4}{y^2}+\frac{9}{(4-x-y)^2}=0\tag 2.$$

This is where I get stuck I'm not entirely sure how to continue. I need to find $x = ?$ and $y = ?$ but this simultaneous equation stumps me.

Comment: Get the LCM of both terms in both equations, bring together, turn into a quadratic in x and y, eliminate... okay, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: As it stands, your system has no solutions (a sum of two positive terms can't be zero). But that's because you made a sign error when computing the derivatives; you need to change the sign of the first term in both (1) and (2). Then note that you must have $1/x^2=4/y^2$, so that $y=\pm 2x$. From there it shouldn't be too hard, I hope!

Comment: What are possible values of x and y? e.g. G(2,3) = -7.166... < 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, to find the maximum and minimum of a function, you have to calculate first the critical points, that is

$$\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$$

In this case, the respective equations are

$$\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{9}{(4-x-y)^{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial y}=-\frac{4}{y^{2}}+\frac{9}{(4-x-y)^{2}}$$

Simplifying you should obtain $x=1-\displaystyle \frac{y}{4}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{5y}{2}=4-x$ which lead to the solution $(x,y)=\bigg\{\displaystyle \frac{2}{3},\displaystyle \frac{4}{3}\bigg\}$

Then you substitute those values in your original function $G(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3})=9$.

As I said, such a point is just a critical point (which means, it could be a local minimum, a local maximum or a saddle point). In order to figure out, we have to use the [Second partial derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

You can see the details in the Wikipedia article. As you already know what you want to prove (that $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3})$ is a local minimum), we expect that $M(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3})>0$ and $f_{xx}(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3})>0$.

I think I'll leave it there. You can do the rest of the calculations.

By the way, the aforementioned procedure works to obtain only a local minimum, maximum or saddle point, not global extrema.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove that the minimum is 9, because the function certainly takes on lower values: for example $G=0$ along a the parabola $(x,y)=(-2t+6t^2,8t+12t^2)$, and clearly $G\rightarrow 0$ as $x,y \rightarrow\infty$. What you have discovered is that there is only one LOCAL minimum, and it is at $(2/3, 4/3)$.